# recycler view with videos, images and text with smooth and non lagging video performance

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, exoplayer

Trying to implement a recycler view with heterogenous view types (videos, images and text). Tried videoview, mediaplayer, exoplayer but video still lags while swiping through the recyclerview and performance is not good. Tried video player manager library but it seems like it only works for a videos only list but it works well.

1. Does someone know of a library or methodology I can adopt to have a recycler view which shows videos, images and text like facebook, instagram or other popular apps?

**Note:** I want the videos to play as it comes into focus and stop playing when not in viewer focus. Not pressing play for playing videos or pressing stop for stopping videos. It should happen automatically.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!